# BottonNavigation fragment viewmodel not cleared on fragment destroy

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

I use BottonNavigation to switch between fragments. The fragments have ViewModels annotated with `@HiltViewModel` and initilized by fragments as `by viewModels()`.

Why do the ViewModels not get cleared/destroyed when the fragments are destroyed (on havigation between fragments)?